# Probability in continuous functions. ( Simple Question )

Tags: probability, random-variables

[image]

Completed the question but can't get my head around part e? Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a line between the two Bus stops

`B-------------------B`

Put the Coffee shop somewhere between the Bus stops

`B------C------------B`

Mark which points are closer to a Bus stop than the Coffee shop and which closer to the Coffee shop

`BbbbcccCccccccbbbbbbB`

It should be easy to see that half the points are closer to the Coffee shop by considering the points to the left of the Coffee shop, and then considering the points to the right of the Coffee shop.